# Retrive data of today and last trhee days and calculate average in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to Retrive data of today and last trhee days and calculate average in mysql.

My query is

```
select  aqi_id, 
r_aqi_id, 
avg(aqi_value), 
added_date 
from 
sfr_aqi 
 order by 
ra.added_date desc 
limit 0,3
```

Please suggest me better way.

Comment: Is there only one entry per date in this table?

Comment: @Anton No there are multiple entries per date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one `NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY` for last three days

```
select  aqi_id, 
r_aqi_id, 
avg(aqi_value), 
added_date 
from 
sfr_aqi 
where ra.added_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
group by aqi_id /* you can also use group by ra.added_date */
order by 
ra.added_date desc 
limit 0,3
```